# How to store 'fully qualified' and 'name only' file name in SSIS variable

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container

I have an SSIS package that has a Foreach Loop container loading all .txt files in a static folder. I'm passing the fully qualified file name as a variable which I'm using in the connection string.

I now need to pass just the filename to a variable to use to execute a stored procedure, trouble is if I change the Foreach Loop collection to just retrieve the filename it prevents the rest from working.

Is there a way to pass both the fully qualified and name only file name to a variable in ssis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, you get to pick one: either fully qualified or file name only. Personally, if everything except the stored procedure expects fully qualified name, I'd create a second variable `FileNameOnly` and either populate it with an expression like

```
RIGHT(@[User::CurrentFileName], FINDSTRING(REVERSE(@[User::CurrentFileName]), "\\", 1 )-1)
```

(this assumes you've stored the value in a variable called `CurrentFileName`)

Or you can use a script Task to assign the value to FileNameOnly and leverage the .NET [System.IO.Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Thanks, I took a similar approach to this. As the folder location is static I created a second variable containing the path, I then joined this, the file name and the file type together.

Answer (score 1):

You can add another variable `@[User::Filename]` and inside the *Foreach loop container* add an *Expression Task* with the following expression:

```
@[User::Filename] = TOKEN(@[User::FilePath],"\\", TOKENCOUNT(@[User::FilePath],"\\"))
```